# How can i get all the minimum values of 1st column, then get all the minimum values of 2nd column of each minimum values of 1st column?

Tags: sql, db2

Hello everyone i'm FinnStark,

I'm working on SQL for a projet and i need to take the min value of an other column where i have the min values of an other column where i have the min values. I have a result that works but it's not optimized at all

This my sql request for now :

```
SELECT  
  Col1,
  Col2,
  Col3,
  MIN(Col4) AS "Col4",
  MIN(Col5) AS "Col5",
  MIN(Col6) AS "Col6"
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY    
  Col1,
  Col2,
  Col3
```

But i need to get all the minimum values of Col4, then get all the minimum values of Col5 of each minimum values of Col4 and then get all the minimum values of Col6 of each minimum values of Col5, So now i have this :

```
select 
  A.Col1,
  A.Col2,
  A.Col3,
  A.Col4,
  A.Col5,
  MIN(A.Col6)
FROM 
  MyTable A
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT
    B.Col1,
    B.Col2,
    B.Col3,
    B.Col4,
    MIN(B.Col5) AS "Col5"
  FROM
    MyTable B
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT     
      Col1,
      Col2,
      Col3,
      MIN(Col4) AS "Col4"
    FROM    
      MyTable
    GROUP BY    
      Col1,
      Col2,
      Col3) C
  ON 
    B.Col1 = C.Col1
    AND B.Col2 = C.Col2
    AND B.Col3 = C.Col3
    AND B.Col4 = C.Col4
  GROUP BY 
    B.Col1,
    B.Col2,
    B.Col3,
    B.Col4 ) D
ON 
  D.Col1 = A.Col1
  AND D.Col2 = A.Col2
  AND D.Col3 = A.Col3
  AND D.Col4 = A.Col4
  AND D.Col5 = A.Col5
GROUP BY 
  A.Col1,
  A.Col2,
  A.Col3,
  A.Col4,
  A.Col5
```

The result of the 2nd request is good but not optimized at all. It take more than 1 minute to have 500 result and i have at least a million of lines.

Could you please tell me if there is a better way to do it?

Sincerely,
FinnStark

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can just write the original data and the result data you want, and we will give  you a SQL by your data.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help me understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand this correctly but try this:

```
SELECT  col1,
        col2,
        col3,
        col4,
        col5,
        MIN(col6) as "col6"
FROM   (
        SELECT  col1,
                col2,
                col3,
                col4,
                MIN(col5) AS "col5",
                col6
        FROM   (SELECT  Col1,
                        Col2,
                        Col3,
                        MIN(Col4) AS "Col4",
                        Col5,
                        Col6
                 FROM   MyTable
                 GROUP  BY Col1,
                           Col2,
                           Col3,
                           Col5,
                           Col6)
        GROUP  BY col1,
                   col2,
                   col3,
                   col4,
                   col6
        )
GROUP BY col1,
         col2,
         col3,
         col4,
         col5
```

Comment: You give me a better answer than i had. it take 3 sec for 500, so that more than 20 times better than what i did. thank you.

Comment: @FinnStark if this solved your problem, please accept it as the answer using the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             MIN(col4) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) as min_col4,
             MIN(col5) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4) as min_col5,
             MIN(col6) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) as min_col6
      FROM MyTable t
     ) t
WHERE col4 = min_col4 AND
      col5 = min_col5 AND
      col6 = min_col6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number() function.

```
select * from
( select col1 , col2 , col3 , col4, col5 , col6 ,
row_number() over
 ( partition by col1, col2 , col3 
   order by col1, col2 , col3 , col4 , col5, col6 ) as rn1
from myTable ) a
where rn1 = 1
```